Java & C# - why I can cast every object to interface (explicitly)
I know the concept of polymorphism and can get the idea, but I yet found an answer to why both in Java and C# the compiler allows you cast some class into interface, although the class doesn't implement the interface at all.
class MyStupidClass{
    
}

interface Ix {
    void doSomehting();
}


//inside some method:
Ix a = (Ix)new MyStupidClass();//compiled and will throw runtime error. 
        
        

It will be crash on the run time. Both in Java and C#.
I can understand the downcasting concept which the child can sometimes be a type of the parent, but not this interface casting.
Edit - adding downcasting example:
class A{
    
}

class A2 extends A{
    
}
class A1 extends A{
    
}

//at some method:


        //A a2 = (A)new MyStupidClass();//won't compiled
        A a3 = new A2();
        
        A1 a4 = (A1)a3;//can make sense because sometimes it will be A1.
        


Just the way the language is defined.  That check is performed at run time, even if the check could be done at compile time in some cases.

In C#, you can define conversions. It doesn't need to be associated with inheritance. You can also convert a double to an int. There's a difference between inheritance and conversion but they use the same syntax.

It can't do the check at compile-time if it's a variable instead of a constant: a child class could implement Ix

They can't check at compile-time since a child class might implement Ix.
They're both smart enough to check at compile-time if the class is final/sealed respectively, since child classes are explicitly not allowed:
C#:
public interface Ix {}
public class MyStupidClass {}
public sealed class MyStupidSealedClass {}

Ix x = (Ix) new MyStupidClass(); // Compiles, throws InvalidCastException
Ix y = (Ix) new MyStupidSealedClass(); // Compilation error: Cannot convert type 'MyStupidSealedClass' to 'Ix'

Java:
public interface Ix {}
public class MyStupidClass {}
public final class MyStupidFinalClass {}

Ix x = (Ix) new MyStupidClass(); // Compiles, throws ClassCastException
Ix y = (Ix) new MyStupidFinalClass(); // error: incompatible types: MyStupidFinalClass cannot be converted to Ix


Why allow it if we do know the class at compile time? The compiler just... doesn't. It doesn't see a constant expression any different from a variable in this case.

I think this is nonsense, Java does a check for the final case too (at least with JDK 21)

@GyroGearless huh. I can't recreate that behavior anymore. I might have just forgot to add "final" when testing? Updated regardless, thanks for pointing that out.

In Java, you can cast an object to an interface type at compile time, but it will fail at runtime if the object doesn’t actually implement the interface, causing a ClassCastException. This is because the compiler assumes you know the object’s type and allows the cast for flexibility.
So in this scenario unless you define MyStupidClass like this it will give an error:
MyStupidClass implements Ix {...}

To avoid this error in general, use an instanceof check before casting:
if (myObject instanceof Ix) {
    Ix a = (Ix) myObject;
}


Cool so why not allow to cast any class to another, and assume that I know the type?

@lingar because an interface can be implemented in a child class. //A a2 = (A)new MyStupidClass();//won't compiled is illegal because A and MyStupidClass are distinct class hierarchies. An A will never be a MyStupidClass and vice versa because of the way Java/C# works
